# How to restrict tensorflow GPU memory usage?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have used tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1 in Ubuntu 18.04 with CUDA 10.0 on Nvidia GeForce RTX 2070 (Driver Version: 415.27).

Code like below was used to manage tensorflow memory usage. I have about 8Gb GPU memory, so tensorflow mustn't allocate more than 1Gb of GPU memory. But when I look on memory usage with `nvidia-smi` command, I see, that it uses ~1.5 Gb despite the fact that I restricted memory quantity with GPUOptions.

```py
memory_config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.12))

memory_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = False

with tf.Session(graph=graph, config=memory_config) as sess:
    output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,
                           feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image, 0)})
```

Why is it going? And how I can avoid this or at least calculate memory needs for every session? I need to make strong restrictions for every process, because I have several paralell instances with different sessions, so I need to be sure, that there will no resource race

BTW, I have tried to set memory_config.gpu_options.allow_growth to False, but it affect nothing. Tensorflow is still allocate memory the same way independently from this flag value. And it's also seems strange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution**
Try with `gpu_options.allow_growth = True` to see how much default memory is consumed in `tf.Session` creation. That memory will be **always** allocated regardless of values.

Based on your result, it should be somewhere less than 500MB. So if you want each process to *truly* have 1GB of memory each, calculate:

```
(1GB minus default memory)/total_memory
```

**Reason**

When you create a `tf.Session`, regardless of your configuration, Tensorflow device is created on GPU. And this *device* requires some minimum memory.

```
import tensorflow as tf

conf = tf.ConfigProto()
conf.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
session = tf.Session(config=conf)
```

Given `allow_growth=True`, there should be no gpu allocation. However in reality, it yields:

> 2019-04-05 18:44:43.460479: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1053] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 15127 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0, compute capability: 6.0)

which occupies small fraction of memory (in my past experience, the amount differs by gpu models). *NOTE:* setting `allow_growth` occupies almost same memory as setting `per_process_gpu_memory=0.00001`, but latter won't be able to create session properly.

In this case, it is **345MB** :

[image]

That is the offset you are experiencing. Let's take a look in case of `per_process_gpu_memory`:

```
conf = tf.ConfigProto()
conf.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.1
session = tf.Session(config=conf)
```

Since the gpu has **16,276MB** of memory, setting `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.1` *probably* makes you think only about 1,627MB will be allocated. But the truth is:

[image]

**1,971MB** is allocated, which however coincides with sum of default memory (345MB) and expected memory (1,627MB).

Comment: Is there a driver-level solution for this, that doesn't depend on the framework? Basically say - prevent all CUDA apps from hogging all GPU memory by default?